# How to find a file in sub-folder on a Google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

This code is only getting a CSV file from the root folder, and I need it to get it from a specific folder.

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
  var  folder= DriveApp.getFolderById("*****"); 
  var file = DriveApp  .getFilesByName("setups.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

Comment: Let the second DriveApp be replaced with folder. Are you absolutely sure it is the only file in that directory with that name?  If not then this function will not work for you.

Comment: const spec_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(specificfolderID); var file = spec_folder.getFilesByName("setups.csv").next();

Comment: error after using your line Exception: Could not parse text.
importCSVFromGoogleDrive @ Code.gs:4

Comment: Give the absolute file path...

Comment: What would that be give e.g

Answer (score 0):

For finding a file on a given folder I use the following solution from [here](https://yagisanatode.com/2018/10/05/google-apps-script-get-file-by-name-with-optional-parent-folder-crosscheck/).

Here is the source code:

```
/*
*param 1: File Name 
*param 2: Parent Folder of File (optional)
*
*returns: Dictionary of file "id" and "error" message {"id": ,"error": }
*  -if there is no error, "id" returns file id and "error" returns false
*  -if there is an error, "id" returns false and "error" returns type of error as a string for user to display or log.
*/
function getFileByName(fileName, fileInFolder) {
  var filecount = 0;
  var dupFileArray = [];
  var folderID = "";

  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    dupFileArray.push(file.getId());

    filecount++;
  };

  if (filecount > 1) {
    if (typeof fileInFolder === 'undefined') {
      folderID = { "id": false, "error": "More than one file with name: " + fileName + ". \nTry adding the file's folder name as a reference in Argument 2 of this function." }

    } else {
      //iterate through list of files with the same name
      for (fl = 0; fl < dupFileArray.length; fl++) {
        var activeFile = DriveApp.getFileById(dupFileArray[fl]);
        var folders = activeFile.getParents();
        var folder = ""
        var foldercount = 0;

        //Get the folder name for each file
        while (folders.hasNext()) {
          folder = folders.next().getName();
          foldercount++;
        };

        if (folder === fileInFolder && foldercount > 1) {
          folderID = { "id": false, "error": "There is more than one parent folder: " + fileInFolder + " for file " + fileName }
        };

        if (folder === fileInFolder) {
          folderID = { "id": dupFileArray[fl], "error": false };

        } else {
          folderID = { "id": false, "error": "There are multiple files named: " + fileName + ". \nBut none of them are in folder, " + fileInFolder }
        };
      };
    };

  } else if (filecount === 0) {
    folderID = { "id": false, "error": "No file in your drive exists with name: " + fileName };

  } else { //IF there is only 1 file with fileName
    folderID = { "id": dupFileArray[0], "error": false };
  };

  return folderID;
};
```

Here the source code for reading CSV file on given folder using `getFileByName()` defined before:

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
  let fileName = "Enter the file name";
  let folder = "Enter the folder name";
  let sheetName = "Enter the sheet Name"; 

  let fileId = getFileByName(fileName, folder) // fileId.id, will contain the file id

  if (fileId.id == false) { // Alerts in case of error
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(fileId.error);
  } else { // file found
    let file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId.id);
    let csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  }
}
```

Comment: can we make code simple lik mine

Comment: @usamaAa, please keep in mind `getFilesByName()` or `getFileById()` from `DriveApp`  searches on the entire Google Drive I don't think there are other functions you can use. You need somehow to overcome this by adding some checking for finding the same file on a different folder and checking the parent is the folder you expect. I think it is very simple considering the limitations we have. Please test it, just copy the function in your script and invoke it.

Comment: ReferenceError: getFileByName is not defined
importCSVFromGoogleDrive @ Code.gs:7

Comment: @usamaAa just copy in a script file the function: `getFileByName`and the function for using it: `importCSVFromGoogleDrive`. It should work.